# Scala pendant for CardLayout

Tags: swing, scala, cardlayout

for learning scala i decided to program a little game. One thing that really bugs me about it, is that i cant find any scala.swing pendant to javas CardLayout.
Basically I want to ask if there is something like the CardLayout in scala swing, or what would be an appropriate way to use javas CardLayout in a scala swing application?
Since I want to keep using scala.swing's Panels I don't really know if its "nice/clean code" if I actually used a Scala Component and gave it a CardLayout. At least this would feel kind of nasty to me. Anyway since I want to learn how to program in scala I'd rather not fall back to Java Components but use scala.swing's. 
Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `CardPanel` class as proposed in issue SI-3933 on the Scala Language web site:
[Request for a scala.swing.CardPanel (uses javax.swing.CardLayout)](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3933).

I would not worry too much about mixing some Java components directly with the [scala-swing](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing) components, since not all Swing classes are wrapped yet.

Answer (score 1):

The README of the [scala.swing GitHub repo](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing)  says (at the time of writing this answer):

> Layout managers and panels are coupled. There is no way to exchange the layout manager of a panel.

So you choose the layout manager by picking a panel. As such I would argue that

> if I actually used a Scala Component and gave it a CardLayout

would be quite alright. There is scala.swing.TabbedPane, but you will get named tabs. If this is not wanted, I suggest taking a look at how 
[scala.swing.BorderPanel](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing/blob/java8-2.11.x/src/main/scala/scala/swing/BorderPanel.scala#L29) combines components and layout managers.